# Accessing Variable Names in for Loop dynamically

Tags: c#

I created following variables:
count_1
count_2
count_3
...

Now I want to check every variable for a condition.

```
for(int j = 1; j <= 10; j++)
    {
        if ("count_" + j == 100)
        {
        ...
        }
     ...
     }
```

Of course this does not work as "count_" + j is not converted into the variable. How do I do that?

Comment: Use an array instead?

Comment: You should use a `List<int>` or an `int[]` (array) instead. You *can* do that in C# but it is not recommend (or rather very strongly discouraged) to do that, it will be error prone.

Comment: agreed use a `List<int> counts` and iterate over that instead

Comment: What you call "variable" exactly? A field/property? Then you can use reflection. To check something in the loop the better idea would be to either switch to appropriate data structure, which are naturally enumerable: e.g. array, `List`, `Dictionary`, etc. or to create it temporarily, only to use shortly for purpose "to enumerate". Something like `new[] { count_1, count_2, ... }` before `for` loop may do.

Comment: @Sinatr `Then you can use reflection` that's what Pac0 ment when he correctly stated `You can do that in C# but it is not recommend (or rather very strongly discouraged) to do that, it will be error prone.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a `List<int>` or an `int[]` (array) instead. They exist exactly for this purpose.

You *could* do "dynamic variable access", in C# but it is not recommended (or rather very strongly discouraged) to do that, it will be error prone.

Example using array :

```
// definition of the array (and initialization with zeros)
int[] counts = new int[10];

// (...)

for(int j = 0; j < counts.Length ; j++)  // note that array indices start at 0, not 1.
{
    if (count[j] == 100)
    {
    ...
    }
 ...
 }
```

---

Here is a similar version with a `List<int>` :

`List`s are a more flexible, and slightly more complex (they can change during size during execution, while an array is fixed, you'll have to recreate a whole new array if you want to change the size.)

```
// definition of the list (and initialization with zeros)
List<int> counts = new List<int>(new int[10]);

// (...)

foreach (int count in counts)  // You can use foreach with the array example above as well, by the way.
{
    if (count == 100)
    {
    ...
    }
 ...
 }
```

---

For your testings, you can initialize values for arrays or lists like this :

```
 int[] counts = new int[] { 23, 45, 100, 234, 56 };
```

or

```
 List<int> counts = new List<int> { 23, 45, 100, 234, 56 };
```

---

Note that you can use `for` or `foreach` for both arrays or `List`s, actually. It depends wether you need to keep track of the "index" for your code somewhere.

If you have trouble using `for` with `List` or `foreach` with array, just let me know.

---

I remember when I first learned programming, that I wanted to do something like your count_1 count_2, etc... Hopefully, discovering the notion of arrays and lists changes my would-be-developer mind, opening a whole new area.

I hope this will set you on the right tracks !

Comment: I would actualy still stick to `List<int> counts` and use `j <= counts.Count` .. this way it is actually dynamic and you could have a longer or shorter list

Comment: To make it more flexible to change - the for loop condition could be changed to _"j < count.Length"_

Comment: @derHugo Yes, or you could use  `foreach` with the `List`

Comment: @Pac0 even better ;)